# How to send file from a multipart form request into another multipart form request

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, multipartform-data, busboy

I currently have a gateway server which receives multipart form requests where each request contains a file and some fields (user id, name of file, etc).  After the server does some validation and a couple other things, I would like to send the original file with a few different fields to a separate file storage server of mine.  In other words, I change the fields, keep the file the same, and send it to a 2nd server.

I currently have this working about 80% of the time, but the rest of the time I get an error on the storage server saying, ***Error: Part terminated early due to unexpected end of multipart data***.  (Happens at the comment 'ERROR PRINTED HERE'). Again, this bug only happens sometimes.

**Gateway Server**

```
const asyncBusboy = require( 'async-busboy' );
const request = reqwuire( 'request-promise' );

async function saveFile( context )
{
    //parses the multipart form request. 'files' is an array of Readable Streams
    const { files, fields } = await asyncBusboy( context.req ); //NEVER breaks here

    if ( files.length == 0 )
        return;

    let form_data =
    {
        directory: 'my/files/directory',
        filename: 'filename',
        readstream: files[0]
        //etc, etc, etc
    };

    let options =
    {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: file_storage_server_url + '/song',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        formData: form_data
    };

    await request( options ); //send to storage server
}
```

**File Storage Server**

```
const asyncBusboy = require( 'async-busboy' );

async function saveFile( context )
{
    const { files, fields } = await asyncBusboy( context.req ); //BREAKS HERE

    //more stuff
}
```

**AsyncBusboy**

What asyncBusboy does internally is it creates a temporary file in the /tmp directory, pipes the incoming file's read stream to the temporary file, creates a read stream to the temporary file, and pushes it onto that 'files' array above. However, I sometimes receive the error I mentioned during the piping.

```
function onFile(files, fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) 
{
  const tmpName = file.tmpName = new Date().getTime()  + fieldname  + filename;
  const saveTo = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(tmpName));

  file.on('end', () => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(saveTo);
    readStream.fieldname = fieldname;
    readStream.filename = filename;
    readStream.transferEncoding = readStream.encoding = encoding;
    readStream.mimeType = readStream.mime = mimetype;
    files.push(readStream);
  });

  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(saveTo);

  writeStream.on('open', () => {
    console.log( "onFile onOpen" ); //Always prints
    file.pipe( fs.createWriteStream(saveTo) );
  });

  //******* ERROR PRINTED HERE ********* 
  file.on( 'error', (error) => { console.log( "Readstream error: " + error ); } );
}
```

**What I THINK is happening**

I think the storage server is reading from the tmp file faster than it's being written to causing it to reach the end of the file and trigger the error, ***Part terminated early due to unexpected end of multipart data.***

**Questions**

Is the overall approach I'm taking wrong?

Is the way async-busboy does things internally fundamentally wrong?

How can I resolve this bug?